# I can't get this to go away in my access 2013 subform

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, subform

[image]

Can someone please help me find the setting to turn the arrow and star off in my subform. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to the properties for the form. Listed in the format tab will be "Record Selectors". If it is "Yes" then select "No". This will correct the issue.